# Как заменить в коде view вызов функции с 2 параметрами на вызов функции с 3 параметрами

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, oracle, plsql

Есть сотни view. Внутри представлений в условии where есть вызовы функции `function1` с 2 параметрами. Хочется заменить на вызовы функции `function2` с 3 параметрами, где первые два такие же, как в функции `function1`

Сейчас: `function1(param1, param2)`

Надо: `function2(param1, param2, param3)`

Надо учесть, что :

1) 1 и 2 параметр так же могут быть функциями со своими параметрами

2) Вызов функции может быть разделен на несколько строк

3) В роли 3го параметра будет всегда одно и то же выражение(на самом деле вызов 
другой функции.

4) Данная функция может быть параметром внутри другой функции

Кажется, что можно сделать замену используя `regexp_replcae`, но не понимаю как написать нужное выражение, чтобы учесть все 4 условия выше. На самом деле не понимаю, как учесть, что параметрами могут быть вызовы других функций.

Comment: Можно ли указать новый параметр (`param3`) первым, т.е. `function2(param3, param1, param2)`? По-моему, это существенно упростит задачу.

Comment: Действительно. Такое простое решение не пришло мне в голову. Оформите ответом)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем конкретном случае замену можно упростить если новый параметр в функции указать первым: `function2(param3, param1, param2)`.

Тогда можно все вызовы `function1(` заменить на вызовы `function2(param3,` и не думать о замене оставшихся параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы решал эту задачу следующим образом: Выгрузил все представления в один файл (в MS SQL есть удобный инструмент для этого, как с этим дела обстоят в Oracle, я не помню), автозаменой через текстовый редактор заменил бы все вызовы и прогнал бы этот файл с измененными представлениями по базе.

Comment: Я не могу заменить "автозаменой". Мне надо, чтобы параметры в вызовах сохранились.